# Showing different div content based on form page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the div content based on what page the user is on Rsform pro multi page form. The div is outside the form.

The form is 4 page and on default the div id "bs01" shows on page load, I've managed to show/hide divs on button clicks with this basic js code

CSS

```
#bs02 {display: none;}
#bs03 {display: none;}
#bs04 {display: none;}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#getaquoteNext").click(function() {
    $("#bs01, #bs03, #bs04").hide();
    $("#bs02").show();
  });
  $("#p2Next").click(function() {
    $("#bs01, #bs02, #bs04").hide();
    $("#bs03").show();
  });
  $("#p3Next").click(function() {
    $("#bs01, #bs02, #bs03").hide();
    $("#bs04").show();
  });
});
```

Main Page HTML

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
    <div id="bs01">Default content</div>
    <div id="bs02">page 2 content</div>
    <div id="bs03">page 3 content</div>
    <div id="bs04">page 4 content</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8">
    <div>BOOKING FORM<br>
  <button id="getaquoteNext"><a href="#">Get a quote</a></button>
  <button id="p2Next"><a href="#">calander</a></button>
  <button id="p3Next"><a href="#">details</a></button>
</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

On page when users enter their details and click on get a quote button (button id="getaquoteNext") the div id="bs02" should show on page 2 and so on.

Comment: The ideal would be to change the div based on page ids rather than button click.

here are the page ids.
page 1
<fieldset class="form-horizontal formContainer" id="rsform_38_page_0"></fieldset>
page 2
<fieldset class="form-horizontal formContainer" id="rsform_38_page_1"></fieldset>
page 3
<fieldset class="form-horizontal formContainer" id="rsform_38_page_2"></fieldset>
page 4
<fieldset class="form-horizontal formContainer" id="rsform_38_page_3"></fieldset>

Comment: Do i understand correctly that you trying to show/hide something on another page then the page you are clicking the button?

Comment: Hi Rick. The form and div are in same page. Here is the actual page: https://www.northlondonappliancerepairs.co.uk/book-a-service.html.  Use postcode "N193NH" to go to second page. My plan is to change the content of the div on the left side of the form.